# MYSQL Select two distinct values

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.id, v.make_id, v.model_id, i.attach_location, mk.make, md.model, v.made_year, u.username
FROM wsq_garage_vehicles v, wsq_garage_vehicles_gallery vg, wsq_garage_images i, wsq_garage_makes mk, wsq_garage_models md, wsq_users u
WHERE v.id = i.vehicle_id
AND mk.id = v.make_id
AND md.id = v.model_id
AND v.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY v.date_updated DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The above returns

```
 id     make_id     model_id    attach_location     make    model   made_year   username
2   25  258     garage_vehicle-2-1373826921.jpg     Ford    Fiesta  2012    John
12  95  836     garage_vehicle-12-1374094864.jpg    Nissan  200SX   1998    Lucky307
12  95  836     garage_vehicle-12-1374095057.jpg    Nissan  200SX   1998    Lucky307
12  95  836     garage_vehicle-12-1374095721.jpg    Nissan  200SX   1998    Lucky307
10  90  752     garage_vehicle-10-1374080908.jpg    Vauxhall    Astra   2003    adm
8   90  756     http://i1279.photobucket.com/albums/y538/allankend...   Vauxhall    Cavalier    1993    muzz
8   90  756     garage_vehicle-8-1374058024.jpg     Vauxhall    Cavalier    1993    muzz
9   25  253     garage_vehicle-9-1374058087.jpg     Ford    Escort  1992    v33bot
1   25  258     garage_vehicle-1-1373755717.jpg     Ford    Fiesta  2005    Beardy
4   43  366     garage_vehicle-4-1373916262.jpg     Land Rover  Defender    1996    Hobbs92
```

What I need is to only return an actual distinct `id` so it would end up something like so

```
 id     make_id     model_id    attach_location     make    model   made_year   username
2   25  258     garage_vehicle-2-1373826921.jpg     Ford    Fiesta  2012    John
12  95  836     garage_vehicle-12-1374095057.jpg    Nissan  200SX   1998    Lucky307
10  90  752     garage_vehicle-10-1374080908.jpg    Vauxhall    Astra   2003    adm
8   90  756     http://i1279.photobucket.com/albums/y538/allankend...   Vauxhall    Cavalier    1993    muzz
9   25  253     garage_vehicle-9-1374058087.jpg     Ford    Escort  1992    v33bot
1   25  258     garage_vehicle-1-1373755717.jpg     Ford    Fiesta  2005    Beardy
4   43  366     garage_vehicle-4-1373916262.jpg     Land Rover  Defender    1996    Hobbs92
```

Comment: Which `attach_location` you want to select for each `id`?

Comment: Any, it could easily be random

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` with any aggregate function with `attach_location` something like this:

```
SELECT 
  v.id, 
  v.make_id, 
  v.model_id, 
  MAX(i.attach_location), 
  mk.make, 
  md.model, 
  v.made_year, 
  u.username
FROM wsq_garage_vehicles v
INNER JOIN wsq_garage_images i            ON v.id      = i.vehicle_id
INNER JOIN wsq_garage_makes mk            ON mk.id     = v.make_id
INNER JOIN wsq_garage_models md           ON md.id     = v.model_id
INNER JOIN wsq_users u                    ON v.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY v.id, 
         v.make_id, 
         v.model_id, 
         mk.make, 
         md.model, 
         v.made_year, 
         u.username
ORDER BY v.date_updated DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**Note that:**

- I used the explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the old join syntax that you were using. It is recommended to use it.
- There was no join condition between the tables `wsq_garage_vehicles v` and `wsq_garage_vehicles_gallery vg` in your query, and it was never used in your query, so I removed it.
- Another way to achieve that is by ignoring the aggregate function for the `attach_location` and it will work fine in MySQL, it will get an arbitrary value for it.

Comment: This works fine once I changed `MAX(i.attach_location)` to `i.attach_location` and removed `INNER JOIN wsq_garage_vehicles_gallery vg ON ... -- join condition`

Comment: @DonaldSutherland - You are joining the tables using the old join syntax by listing the `FROM` with `,` between them with the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause, but the recommended way is using the explicit `INNER JOIN` keywork with the join condition on the `ON` clause. Using the `MAX(i.attach_location) ` is just a work around to select a value for each grouped `id`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @DonaldSutherland - Note that I removed the table `wsq_garage_vehicles_gallery vg` from the `FROM` clause because it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT v.id, v.make_id, v.model_id, min(i.attach_location), mk.make, md.model, v.made_year, u.username
FROM wsq_garage_vehicles v, wsq_garage_vehicles_gallery vg, wsq_garage_images i, wsq_garage_makes mk, wsq_garage_models md, wsq_users u
WHERE v.id = i.vehicle_id
AND mk.id = v.make_id
AND md.id = v.model_id
AND v.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY v.date_updated DESC
group by v.id, v.make_id, v.model_id, mk.make, md.model, v.made_year, u.username
LIMIT 10
```

Furthemore you can not query i.attach_location. In result your query would easy:

```
SELECT v.id, v.make_id, v.model_id, mk.make, md.model, v.made_year, u.username
FROM wsq_garage_vehicles v, wsq_garage_vehicles_gallery vg, wsq_garage_images i, wsq_garage_makes mk, wsq_garage_models md, wsq_users u
WHERE v.id = i.vehicle_id
AND mk.id = v.make_id
AND md.id = v.model_id
AND v.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY v.date_updated DESC
LIMIT 10
```